# undefined method `keys' for "writing of flash message" :string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

Hello Im getting this error not sure how to go about it as this is the first experience for this.

- undefined method `keys' for "You have submitted your Completed Writing Document":String

Im updating a db row and then after success it redirects and the error is highlighted over the `redirect_to your_reservations_path, flash: "You have submitted your Completed Writing Document"`

My controller reservation:

```
def update
  if @reservation.update(reservation_params)
    puts 'first'
    if reservation_params.has_key?(:completed_doc)
      puts 'second'
      @reservation.update_attributes turned_in: true
      redirect_to your_reservations_path, flash: "You have submitted your Completed Writing Document"
    else

      redirect_to your_reservations_path, alert: "Oops, something went wrong..."
    end
  else
    render '_edit'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change it to `:notice`

```
redirect_to your_reservations_path, 
            notice: "You have submitted your Completed Writing Document"
```

Comment: works this way thanks! accepting in 10 mins it says ^^